# Brightness keys F4 and F5 not working on Dell XPS 15.6 Laptop

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, dell, brightness

Please provide me a solution how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have proprietary graphics drivers installed?

Comment: @SirCharlo A laptop's *backlight* is not controlled by the graphics card or graphics drivers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit "*/etc/default/grub*" as root.

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now, look for the line that looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Append "*acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux*" to the end of that line, before the end quotes, so that the line now looks something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Save and close the file, and run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now, reboot, and test out the brightness keys. They should be working correctly now.

Comment: That leaves my screen flickering unless it is on full brightness.

Comment: Works on my Dell inspiron 3521 on Ubuntu 13.04 . Thanks :)

Comment: I have Dell Inspiron 7520, this solved my problem, but the system became unstable. The brightness controls had some delay before actually changing the brightness, also when I pressed some brightness button the reaction was as if I pressed it twice. When I pressed those buttons quickly and chaotically the system could stuck, the mouse pointer speed reduced and the KDE even logged me off. So very weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/762670

It's for the XPS 17, but maybe it works on the 15" model too.

Comment: I didnt check ur solution,because the above one worked....still anyways thanks for the effort :)