# Screen brightness keys not working

Tags: brightness

Am using a dell n4010 laptop with Ubuntu 13.04 installed in it along with windows 8(dual boot).  The screen brightness keys are not working.Does anyone have the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread [Brightness Controls Not Working on a Dell Inspiron N4010 Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289171/brightness-controls-not-working-on-a-dell-inspiron-n4010-laptop).