# Brightness Not Responsive

Tags: 13.04, brightness

In Ubuntu 13.04, whenever I decrease brightness, it still stays at its highest, and won't decrease. What's the fix?

Info

13.04, using Gnome Environment, but its Ubuntu 13.04. 
Dell Inspiron

Also, cannot get updates at ALL

"Failed to get repository information." 
Sudo apt-get update also gives errors at end.

Comment: about the errors of update, can you give us examples please

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the grub configuration:

```
$gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

add:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

after:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

then update the grub and restart:

```
$update-grub && reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and did the following to resolve the issue.
Firstly, do this...

1. Open up the `Terminal` and type **sudo gedit /etc/rc.local**
2. Then add this line before **exit 0**

   **echo 980 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness**
3. Now save the file. You can adjust value as you wish.

The above steps will hold the brightness on reboots. Next, see this answer given to my question regarding the same issue [Brightness Controls Not Working on a Dell Inspiron N4010 Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/a/289177/152748).

Comment: thanks. It worked, but now the same thing happens. It is dimmer, but the brightness won't respond to my "command" of making it brighter, it'll just stay dim.

Comment: You also have to do the second part to make it work.