# 13.04 Upgrade – Brightness not working

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, brightness

Up until yesterday I was running Ubuntu 12.10 on my Dell Latitude E6530. Recently I played around with the nvidia settings, which caused my brightness control to stop working. However, I could fix it by adding `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` as advised in [1].

Now, last night I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 because I needed are newer kernel. After that, the brightness control once again stopped working. But this time, [1] doesn't help. I have also tried the methods in [2]:

- `acpi_backlight=vendor` in `/etc/default/grub`
- `acpi_osi=Linux` in `/etc/default/grub`
- `echo $SOME_VALUE | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness`

None of them are working, the brightness just doesn't change, but that's about all I could find for this problem. Any ideas on how I can get my brightness control back?

---

[1] https://askubuntu.com/a/270830

[2] https://askubuntu.com/a/289178/213036

Comment: Have you tried removing the Nvidia modules enterely?

Comment: @Braiam Removed them altogether and tried different versions of nvidia drivers. Nothing.

Comment: Just in case, did you remember to do `sudo update-grub` after modifying `/etc/default/grub`? If not, try both permutations with and without `acpi_backlight=vendor`. Also, with each permutations, try sequentially modifying other files at `/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`. (This may be of interest: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=110984 )

Comment: I just tried again to make sure I used `update-grub`. I tried every permutation I could think of, but nothing. The only thing I notice is that if I change the `brightness` file and use the brightness key, I can see that Ubuntu's little popup responded to it. But the brightness itself just doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue with my Sony Vaio. I tried all the methods that you have listed, but there was no effect.

However, in grub, editing lines as follows helped me. (Be sure to backup grub before any editing as a standard practice).

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=legacy"
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=legacy"

<sub>**Note**: We are using `acpi_backlight=legacy` instead of `acpi_backlight=vendor` here.</sub>

After saving, run command `$ sudo update-grub` and reboot your laptop.

Once I did that, the commands `cat` and `tee` started working for me to display and change brightness from Terminal.

- This will give you maximum numeric value of brightness that your screen supports.

  ```
  $ cat /sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight/max_brightness
  ```
- This will set your screen brightness value to  your specified value, between 0 to **max_brightness**.

  ```
  $ echo <brightness_value> | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness
  ```

For more information, refer to this backlight [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#ACPI).

Comment: The `max_brightness` changed from `15` to `100`, but setting `brightness` to any value still has no effect =/

Comment: @IngoBürk, I don't have any more suggestions as of now, since I am looking for a definite answer too.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394964/msi-ge70-screen-brightness).

The nomodeset kernel parameter may disable the brightness adjustment when used with acpi_backlight=vendor. Remove the former and add the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downgrading back to 12.10. 13.04 is in beta phase and still undergoing testing.

To answer your question, check your display and connection, the brightness may be low there. You may also have a bad graphics module in your computer (if this is a laptop, it may be the back light bulb). In either case, try hooking your computer up to a different display.

Hope I helped, If not, I am sure there is a simple fix we are overlooking. Just remember the 6 levels of Linux, in order to do one thing, you must fix six other things first. :)

Comment: Downgrading isn't an option, I am required to have at least 13.04 for other work-related reasons (which could maybe be fixed otherwise, but I tried that a lot before ugprading to 13.04). Yes, it is a laptop and I doubt it's a bad bulb since it is stuck on the brightest (not least brightest) setting. My laptop is, at work, always hooked up to a second display, but I've never been able to control the brightness of that display through my laptop brightness. I appreciate your time to answer, though.

Comment: 13.04 is not in beta phase! This was the second-last release.