# Dell ACPI Backlight brightness doesn't change on 20.04

Tags: brightness, acpi, backlight, xbacklight

I have a Dell G3 3579 (Secure Boot Disabled) with Ubuntu 20.04 fully updated. The brightness cannot be changed in either the OS or with the hardware keyboard buttons. Here's what I tried:

- I reinstalled Nvidia drivers for GTX 1050 Mobile
- I changed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in
  `/etc/default/grub` to:

  ```
  "quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=linux"
  ```
- With this, the transparent backlight appears but the backlight still does not change.
- I also tried changing acpi_backlight to video
- I ran `ls /sys/class/backlight` and there is one entry called
  `dell_backlight`
- I installed `backlight-controller` but no effect. Errors were output in the terminal when I ran the program from the terminal and moved the sliders
- Please check and decypher the output of `dmesg | grep "ACPI"` [here](https://pastebin.com/QDaBzPLg)

When I had Manjaro installed the brightness could be changed both in the OS and the hardware buttons. Without the brightness working. I will have to keep the laptop plugged in because of the power draw of the screen.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub` from:

```
"quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=linux"
```

to

```
"quiet splash acpi_backlight=legacy"
```

works perfectly! It also fixed the 'nvidia-settings' blank window issue.

Check this post for full info [13.04 Upgrade – Brightness not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/373454/13-04-upgrade-brightness-not-working)